# R setting limits to row values in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
a <- c(1:5)
b <- c(5:9)
c <- c(7:11)
min <- c(2,7,4,5,3)
max <- c(5,9,12,8,7)
df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,min,max)
df1
```

How can I set row limits, so the minimum and maximum values of each row a,b,c is set by the row values in columns: min and max?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Row a,b,c? a, b, c will be columns. And can you give us a sample of the required output

Comment: Probably each row 'of' a, b, c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this easier if you think of the data frame as a list of columns:

```
mins <- lapply(df1[1:3], function(x) pmax(x, df1$min))
maxs <- lapply(mins, function(x) pmin(x, df1$max))
```

Then you can rebuild the data.frame:

```
df2 <- do.call(cbind, maxs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your elegant solution.

Comment: No problem, but if you're really hoping to speed things up, I think @carl is right in suggesting casting things as matrices - they're meant to be faster, so you might want to benchmark `pmax(pmin(mat, df1$max), df1$min)` - things will get recycled along the columns of the matrix `mat` so no need for an apply.

Answer (score 2):

```
f <- function(X){
  X[X < df1$min] <- df1$min[X < df1$min]
  X[X > df1$max] <- df1$max[X > df1$max]
  X
  }

sapply(df1[,1:3] ,  f)
```

Comment: Nice, but I'd like to see a time trial (microbenchmark) of this against my solution. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but your right, it won't be fast. Gavin;s soln is fastest

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
## Function that checks the limits of each column
limit <- function(x, mn, mx) {
    pmax(pmin(x, mx), mn)
}

## Then build your data.frame 
df2 <- data.frame(a = limit(a, min, max), b = limit(b, min, max), c = limit(c, min, max), min, max)
```

Using apply is another option on an existing `data.frame`

```
df3 <- apply(df1[ ,1:3], 2, limit, mn = min, mx = max)
```

I hope it helps,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much this:  EDIT I apologize: it should be "pmin" for "parallel minimum" and "pmax"

```
for(j in 1:3 ) df1[,j]<-pmin(df1[,j],df1[,5])
for(j in 1:3 ) df1[,j<-pmax(df1[,j],df1[,4])
```

PS you're probably better off with a `matrix`

Comment: Isn't `min` a global minimum - I get that it sets the value of a whole column to a single value.  I thought the OP wanted it to be a row-wise constraint?

Comment: @GavinKelly you are absolutely correct-- I should have used `pmin` .